# Is it possible to hide only overflowing text but not overflowing child absolute divs?

Tags: jquery, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to implement a sidebar with a tree like list. I want each element in the tree to fill one line only - no overflow, no new line / word wrap. An `overflow: hidden;` could be a good solution, but there's another requirement - each line will have an absolute div as a tooltip / popover (bootstrap's popover), which I don't want to hide or 'clip' (it suppose to be in some top layer).
The problem is that the popover is generated as a child of the element that needs to be hidden if overflowing. How can I achieve a behavior that matches the attached image?

Example:

[image]

Comment: Please post your code (what you have tried so far).

Answer (score 1):

Wrap each line of text in another element (such as a `<div>` or `<span>`) then apply `overflow: hidden` to them, not the parent.

Your current:

```
<div style="container" style="overflow: hidden">
    My text
    <div class="popup">My popup</div>
    Some more text
</div>
```

What you should do:

```
<div style="container">
    <div class="text" style="overflow: hidden">My text</div>
    <div class="popup">My popup</div>
    <div class="text" style="overflow: hidden">Some more text</div>
</div>
```

(remember to do this in your stylesheet, not using inline styling)

Comment: Hi Jared, i added an example to your answer, hope you don't mind :) Upvoted as well, and this should be the accepted answer IMO.

Comment: I don't see the example, but you're welcome to edit it to add one. :)

Comment: I did edit, but it said my edit will be published after it's been reviewed by the community. Didn't you get any notice from SO to review my edit?

Comment: @Mtz I just noticed it. Apparently it was rejected by 3 people and I need 2k rep to do my own review. Go figure. I've edited my post with my own example. Thanks for the suggestion. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `z-index` on your popover! :)

See the usage and definition [here](http://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/pr_pos_z-index.asp).

Try this example as well: http://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_zindex

Comment: Definitely won't help: the problem is that as absolute positioned child element, if the parent has overflow:hidden it will be clipped. @Mohammad Areeb Siddiq

Answer (score 0):

The child should have negative margin and no absolute displaying needed there because that way it would not affect to the parent text overflowing.

Example:
http://jsbin.com/akivid/3/edit

```
<div class='out'>
TEXT 
    <div class='in'>          
      <span class='triangle-left'></span>
      TEXT
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.out{
  width:100px;
  background-color:gold;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  padding:10px;
}
.in{
 background-color:lime;
  margin-right:-20px;
  margin-left:20px;
  width:40px;
  float:right;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  position:relative;
 padding:5px;
}
.triangle-left {
  position:absolute;
  left:-15px;
  top:10px;
  width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 10px solid transparent;
    border-right: 15px solid lime;
    border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
}
```

Comment: You have used word-wrap. I need hidden overflow, which means, if text goes to all way to the right border of parent div it will be hidden, not break into a new line. @2astalavista